# How can I get date like nov-18 in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get SQL date from 2018-11-01 to nov-18.

Comment: Who upvotes these questions?

Comment: Personally, I'd worry about the display format in your presentation layer. Formatting a date means changing it from a `date(time)` data type to a `varchar`; which brings its own set of problems.

Answer (score 4):

Use `format()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dc1c94047951719179520e2681101321)**

```
select format(cast('2018-11-01' as date),'MMM-yy', 'en-US')
```

OUTPUT:

```
dateval
Nov-18
```

Comment: I am getting error like this when I tried using this "Argument data type nvarchar(max) is invalid for argument 1 of format "function.

Comment: @dattuchowdarybolla, updated it - you can check now

Comment: `format(cast('2018-11-01' as date),'MMM-yy' ,'en-US')` would be safer in that it will return the specified results irrespective of the language of the login that runs it

Comment: @MartinSmith, thank u - update it

Comment: Wait, you're storing dates as a `varchar(MAX)` @dattuchowdarybolla ? Why???

Comment: I got the answer, I converted the date into datetime and later formatted.

Comment: @Larnu - even worse. `nvarchar(max)` so it will take double the space (despite never having a non ASCII character)

Comment: How to get 2018-08 then?